# UIImagePickerController capturing image instead of video

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, quickblox

I'm using the code below to capture image and video using `UIImagePickerController`. The code works perfectly, until I initiate a Video Chat using Quickblox. After I initiate and end the Video Chat session, the `UIImagePickerController` code to capture the video stops working i.e. instead of capturing video, it presents the controller for taking Picture. Any thoughts?

**Capture Image**

```
UIImagePickerController *controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
controller.delegate = self;
controller.allowsEditing = NO;
controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
controller.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Capture Video**

```
UIImagePickerController *controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
controller.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];
controller.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeLow;
controller.videoMaximumDuration = 90;
controller.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with Quickblox. As per Quickblox support, we should setup and use a custom video capture session -- which might fix this issue. I've yet to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

The UIImagePickerController also has a cameraCaptureMode property. Set that to the desired mode.

```
enum {
   UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto ,
   UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo 
};
typedef NSUInteger  UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureMode;
```

Comment: It has no effect, and in some cases, produces crash.